# MQ ERROR Code 2035 and 2063

Tags: ibm-mq

Whenever we try to connect to websphere MQ server through .NET Application we get Error message code 2063.Also some time 2035.We tried to connect to MQ Server using both XMS.NET and plain old amsmqdnet.dll..how authentication/authorization works when we connect to MQ server from .net applicatio?please guide...

```
using System;
using IBM.XMS;
  XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory;
                  IConnectionFactory cf;

                  // Get an instance of factory.
                  factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

                  // Create WMQ Connection Factory.
                   cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

                  // below properties r set
                   //cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "hostname");
                 // cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT,0);
                //  cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
                  //cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                //  cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "queuemanager name");
                 // cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_NAME, "queuename");

                  // Create connection.
                  var mqConnection = cf.CreateConnection();
```

Comment: It would help if you could post your code. Also version of MQ Server and Client you are using will also help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Please also let us know if you have AMS installed, and supply the error messages from the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG file and client side error log as well.

Comment: Websphere MQ client 8

Comment: commented properties are actually set in code

Comment: @MoragHughson....how to check error log ..any path?

Comment: We have set userId in MCA property in channels properties nd it started working...any idea what this MCA stands for?